# how to remove text output when plotting?

Tags: python

below is the code to plot two stock curves.

```
study_symbol='TQQQ'
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
color = '#0072B2'
ax1.set_xlabel('Days')
ax1.set_ylabel('SPY', color=color)
ax1.plot(df2['Days'], df2['SPY'], color=color, ls='-', label='SPY')
ax1.scatter(df['Days'], df['SPY'], color=color, marker='o')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
ax1.legend(loc=(0.01, .94), frameon=False)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'r'
ax2.set_ylabel(study_symbol, color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(df2['Days'], df2[study_symbol], color=color, ls='--', label=study_symbol)
ax2.scatter(df['Days'], df[study_symbol], color=color, marker='x')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
ax2.legend(loc=(0.01, .89), frameon=False)

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.title(r'$\bfStock\ of\ SPY$' +
          '\ncorrelates with\n' +
          r'$\bfStock\ of $'+r'$\bf\ '+study_symbol+'$')
plt.xticks(ticks=df['Days'].tolist(), labels=df['Days'].tolist())
```

after running the above code, it created a lot of texts like below. I am not sure how to avoid these text output. I just need the plot. Thanks

```
([<matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c2a400>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c2a3d0>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357ac70d0>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c39d00>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c8c280>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c8cd30>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c974c0>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c97c10>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c9d3a0>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c97b50>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c8ca30>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c80df0>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357c9de50>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357de35e0>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XTick at 0x1e357de3d30>,

...
 [Text(0, 0, '0'),
  Text(1, 0, '1'),
  Text(2, 0, '2'),
  Text(3, 0, '3'),
  Text(4, 0, '4'),
  Text(5, 0, '5'),
  Text(6, 0, '6'),
  Text(7, 0, '7'),
```

Comment: Adding `plt.show()` at the end generally works

Comment: You can also try adding a semicolon at the end of the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mohil Patel and bb1 point out, adding plt.show(); should do it for you.

```
fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.title(r'$\bfStock\ of\ SPY$' +
          '\ncorrelates with\n' +
          r'$\bfStock\ of $'+r'$\bf\ '+study_symbol+'$')
plt.xticks(ticks=df['Days'].tolist(), labels=df['Days'].tolist())
plt.show()
```

Comment: You don't need to do both things. `plt.show()` returns `None` so it will not produce text output.

Comment: force of habit. good to know @bb1